# Eadui font and luatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

Eadui, based on the hand of an eleventh-century scribe, is freely available at the [Open Font Library](http://openfontlibrary.org/font/eadui). I can use Eadui easily with `xelatex`, but `lualatex` produces a puzzling error.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Eadui}
\begin{document}
The cat sat on the mat.
\end{document}
```

gives this with `xelatex`:

[image]

But the same file compiled with `lualatex` yields this:

```
./example.tex:3: LuaTeX error ...xmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fontloade
r.lua:8299: attempt to index local 'si' (a nil value).
<to be read again>
\scan_stop:
l.3 \setmainfont{Eadui}


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./example.tex:3: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "Eadui" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.3 \setmainfont{Eadui}
```

I’m using TeX Live 2014, but I’ve had this problem since I first tried the font several years ago. Eadui is installed in `~/.fonts`, and it’s listed in `luaotfload-names.lua.gz`.  Google had no matches for “attempt to index local 'si' (a nil value)”.  Any idea what that message could mean, how to begin debugging the font, or how to work around the problem?

Comment: looks like a problem with the luaotfloader. I'll drop a line to the maintainer.

Comment: Thérèse, @Herbert: Definitely a bug, [I’m on it](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/248), but if there’s an official fix unfortunately it [will take a while](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2014/079069.html).

Comment: Thanks, @phg, and take your time. The scribe has waited patiently since the 11th century; a few more weeks won’t hurt.  And best wishes to Hans.

Comment: Thank you, @phg, for the latest update to `luaotfload`. Eadui now works perfectly with `luatex`.

Comment: It looks like this problem is solved. Could someone explain what the fix was in an answer?

Comment: @AndrewCashner That may be premature: according to https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/248, the official fix is yet to come.  But, yes, this temporary solution works.

Comment: There’s an upstream fix now that corrects the sparse table; will be part of next Luaotfload.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report. The bug was fixed upstream recently.

Comment: There may be more to my question than a bug report:  I know where to find explanations of most error messages (e.g., _The LaTeX Companion_), but `luatex` is newer than those resources and sometimes produces error messages I can’t find in books or by googling.  That’s what I was getting at with “Any idea what that message could mean?”  Possibly I could edit the question to highlight the problem of interpreting newer error messages, but that question may be premature, since `luatex` is evolving.  But eventually it would be useful if the site compiled a list of these newer messages.